# The grad of F.normalize in pytorch is strange

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation

The grad of F.normalize in pytorch is nearly zero.

Codes in python3 & pytorch==1.3.0:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([[1, 0]]), requires_grad=True)
x_norm = F.normalize(x, dim=-1)
z = x_norm.mm(x_norm.t())
print('x_norm', x_norm)
print('z', z)

x.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
x_norm.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
z.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
z.backward()
```

Output:

```
x_norm tensor([[1., 0.]], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
z tensor([[1.]], grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
tensor([[1.]])                      # z grad
tensor([[2., 0.]])                  # x_norm grad
tensor([[0., 0.]])                  # x grad
```

Why is the grad of x zero? 'x.grad' gives the same result.

According to the chain rule, I think the result should be [-1, 1]*[2, 0]=[-2, 0].

Actually, when I use the codes above in a whole network, the grad works fine.

Is there anything wrong with my codes?

Tried

```
x_norm = x / torch.sqrt((x[0, 0]**2 + x[0, 1]**2))
```

The same result.

Tried CUDA, the same.

Tried the following codes, replacing `x_norm` with `y_norm`:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([[1, 0]]), requires_grad=True)
y = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([[2, 0]]), requires_grad=True)
x_norm = F.normalize(x, dim=-1)
y_norm = F.normalize(y, dim=-1)
z = x_norm.mm(y_norm.t())

y.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
x.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
x_norm.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
z.register_hook(lambda g: print(g))
z.backward()
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1.]])                      # z grad
tensor([[2., 0.]])                  # x_norm grad
tensor([[0., 0.]])                  # y grad
tensor([[0., 0.]])                  # x grad
```

However, if I replace `z = x_norm.mm(y_norm.t())` with `z = x_norm.mm(y.t())`, `y` has its non-zero value while `x` doesn't.

Also tried to put `F.normalize` in the middle of the codes:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

#x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1, 2), requires_grad=True)
x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([[1,0]]), requires_grad=True).cuda()                                                                                            y = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([[2,0]]), requires_grad=True).cuda()
x1 = x * 2
x1_norm = F.normalize(x1, dim=-1)                                                                                                                                         

print('x1', x1)
z = x1_norm.mm(y.t())
print('x1_norm', x1_norm)
print('z', z)
y.register_hook(lambda g: print('y', g))
x.register_hook(lambda g: print('x', g))
x1.register_hook(lambda g: print('x1', g))
x1_norm.register_hook(lambda g: print('x1_norm', g))
z.register_hook(lambda g: print('z', g))
z.backward()
```

Output

```
x1 tensor([[2., 0.]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
x1_norm tensor([[1., 0.]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
z tensor([[2.]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
z grad tensor([[1.]], device='cuda:0')            # z grad
x1_norm grad tensor([[2., 0.]], device='cuda:0')  # (x*2)_norm grad
x1 grad tensor([[0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')       # x*2 grad
y grad tensor([[1., 0.]], device='cuda:0')        # y grad
x grad tensor([[0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')        # x grad
```

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of `z` is simply its derivative, that is to say 1.

The gradient of `x_norm` is the gradient of `mm(x_norm)` computed in `(1; 0)`. That is to say, if `x_norm = (x; y)`, its gradient is `2 * (x; y)`, which gives `(2; 0)` in `(1; 0)`.

Next, as you have `(x / norm(x)) * (x / norm(x))^T = 1` which is a constant, the gradient of `x` is naught.

EDIT: you have the following equation:

[image: latex equation]

Taking the gradient of a constant yields 0.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the last sentence further? I have tried to replace `x_norm.mm(x_norm.t())` with `x_norm.mm(y_norm.t())`, but nothing happens. However, if I replace it with `x_norm.mm(y.t())` or `x_norm.mm(x.t())`, the one without 'norm' has its
non-zero grad value.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I know the problem now and you are totally right. However, I have tried to replace it with `x_norm.mm(y_norm.t())`, and `y` is totally different from `x`, which means z is not a constant, but the grad is zero, too. I have also tried to put `F.normalize` in the middle of the codes, but the grad is zero either. Actually, the grad becomes zero from `F.normalize` to input. Could you help me for explaining this? You can see my codes in the edited question.

Comment: The partial derivative of `z` relative to `y1` is computed here: http://shorturl.at/bwAQX you see that for `y = (y1, y2) = (2, 0)`, it gives `0`. The same goes for `y2`: http://shorturl.at/dmvB7 I've plugged `x = (1, 0)` as in your code